# /etc/rc.local not being run everytime a user logs in via ssh

Tags: systemd, rc, rc.local

I have set up the `/etc/systemd/system/rc-local.service` as follows:

```
[Unit]
 Description=/etc/rc.local Compatibility
 ConditionPathExists=/etc/rc.local

[Service]
 Type=forking
 ExecStart=/etc/rc.local start
 TimeoutSec=0
 StandardOutput=tty
 RemainAfterExit=yes
 SysVStartPriority=99

[Install]
 WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The rights are set up properly on the `/etc/rc.local` script:

```
File: /etc/rc.local
...
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    0/    root)
```

The service (hence the rc.local script) is started successfully every time the machine starts up.

However, the script does not get run every time a user logs in via ssh.

What am I missing? I'm starting to believe that I have the concept wrong.

Comment: Yes, you have the concept wrong. The easiest way to do what you want may be to modify `/etc/pam.d/ssh` (filename may vary) and add a line like `session optional pam_exec.so /etc/rc.local`.

Comment: If a user logs in three times simultaneously, do you want three instances of the service running? If not, you need to put in some kind of locking mechanism.

Comment: @doneal24 Thanks for the pointer about the concept. I actually fixed by using a `/etc/profile.d/` script

Answer (score 1):

There was a confusion between `rc.local` use case and using a script in `/etc/profile.d`